# Error with installing pywin

Tags: python, pip, package, pywin

Python version: 3.6.0

So I tried to download PyWin using pip, and I got the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oowkQ.png)

I'm not sure what other details to include.

I'm using windows 10 64-bit

I tried googling around and found nothing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package at PyPI is rather old and only supports Python 2.5 to 3.3.

Comment: does it support python 2.7.12?